# Deploying React + Spring boot Rest + mysql on one cloud – is it possible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, web-applications, digital-ocean, springboot

I have finished by project coding, and now I want to launch it online.
I need some consulting about my deployment process.

At first I though that I will use the “free using” first year of AWS, but very soon I have understand that each little service more then the minimum will cost money and not a little bit.

**My project contains** one server which running spring-boot-web application (launch Tomcat) , and use mysql database. In addition there is other server of React.js for the client side, which interact with the server.

Traffic best scenario : 10,000 per a month.

The price does play a role. It’s pretty basic app, I yet know if it will bring profits, and I don’t want to invest much money in this currently. But this app is here for stay, so I need to make it with sane service that even if it will grow the cost will be logic. I don't want to pay more then **10$ per month**, and prefer even less.

I have tried , as said above to use AWS. Success to upload draft app with Elastic Beanstalk. But the convenient service include the DB which I think drag a billing.

So I want to take some cloud like Digital ocean offers, or EC2 of AWS  or something else and to put the server of Spring boot + mysql on it (with Backups too) , and also to put the React server on it.

Is it possible? And what is your recommendation for my needs. And what reference I should learn in context to the answer?

Comment: You might be able to run all that on free tier. I have Nginx, PHP and MySQL on a t2.nano, so a t2.micro with 1GB RAM you might be ok. Using RDS is better, but not at the price you want to pay.

Answer (score 0):

There is a free tier of RDS for MySQL, Beanstalk only uses EC2 which also has a free tier as well. So were you going over the limits or?

Comment: I have follow this guide https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/deploying-a-spring-boot-application-on-aws-using-aws-elastic-beanstalk/ which say to choose t2.small db that make charges. 
Only the t2.micro is and it's seems to me too small... 
Also didn't get yet how to deploy React but Have understand that it's service of S3>web hosting and don't know if it's free. 

In anycase I want to know how much it will cost, after the year will be gone

Comment: When you say t2.micro "seems too small", is that based on insufficient performance, problems with throughput, or just you thinking it seems too small. You can do a heck of a lot with a t2.micro.